# Equivalent for arc4random() in Android

Tags: android, math, arc4random

I have arc4random() for random in my IOS Project to calculate the random number between 2 to (2^32)-1 it returns (uint32_t values). I want convert the same project to Android I don't  know what is the Equivalent function for arc4random() in android to calculate the random number I have also added some of my random numbers in ios below please look on it give me some suggestion to calculate the random number in Android.

Example Random numbers:
1902136219,
575648775,
2003297918,
166044218,
1320498814.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Java's [Random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) class, as in:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int r = rand.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 0):

use Math.random(). 
You can set a range.
For example to get a random number between 1 and 10 you would do:

```
int range =  (maxValue - minValue) + 1;
int randomValue = (Int)(Math.random() * range) + min;
```